# Digital audio between Intel Atom E640 and ADAU1445

Tags: drivers, audio, alsa

Background information:
I have a ADAU1445 DSP from Analog Devices connected to multiple audio sources through the Serial Input pairs. One of these sources is an Intel Atom E640 processor running Angström Linux, connected specifically to input pair 8 on the ADAU1445. Also, the clock lines from the Intel is connected to the ADAU1445 no. 8 clock lines.

Research:
It appears that the ADAU1445 accepts a range of different digital audio formats (TDM2 (Stereo), TDM4, TDM8, TDM16). But the Atom E640 outputs in Intel High Definition Audio format (codename Azalia). My understanding of the specifics is not very good. But in my research, i think i have discovered that the snd_hda_intel ALSA driver in the Linux kernel is responsible for the output.

Question:
Is it possible to write a custom ALSA driver, that will output audio over the same pins as the original snd_hda_intel driver, but in I2S TDM2 (Stereo) format instead of Intel HDA (Azalia) format?

I am not even sure whether or not my questions is valid, or if i have made some false assumptions, so any help or comments is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Atom is designed for 'standard' PCs with a cheap HDA codec; its hardware does not support any other audio format.

Comment: How come the hardware doesn't support it? Isn't it just a question of writing a different audio driver?

Comment: The audio output pins cannot be controlled directly by software.